# Cluster multiple edges between two nodes

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm using vis.js for network visualization. 
My idea is to develop a solution like Google Maps Zoom in the sense that it clusters edges and nodes when not zoomed.

I want to cluster nodes apart from clustering multiple edges between the same two nodes.
Like a cluster nodes, when clustered edge is zoomed or clicked, I want to show all different edges with more information.

I haven't found an answer in vis.js documentation for clustering, issues and questions. Is this feature available?

Comment: Please show what have you tried and describe specific issues you have faced. As currently written, your question is not very clear.. You should improve your grammar, I can't see enough verbs in the idea description to understand what it is.. Best regards

Comment: Thanks! (And sorry for the grammar)

What I want to do is something like:
1) https://i.imgur.com/TIADE9J.png

When double click on the aggregated edge:
2) https://i.imgur.com/bYutc8P.png

Nodes:
{id: 1, label: 'Node 1'}
{id: 2, label: 'Node 2'}
{id: 3, label: 'Node 3'}

Edges:
{from: 1, to: 2}
{from: 2, to: 3}
{from: 2, to: 3}
{from: 2, to: 3}

I only found this solution with 'physics enabled': false for the first image and true for the second.

Is there other solution? I want only for the clicked edges and don't want to change general options of the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, the term "clustering" is applicable to nodes only in vis.js' vocabulary. However, what you can do is to hide edges.

You have to set an [on](http://visjs.org/docs/network/index.html#method_on) [click](http://event_click) handler where you grab the selected edge, get its `from` and `to` nodes (you have to decide what to do if there's more than one selected edge, though), find the edges connecting them and [hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40609135/how-to-hide-graphs-branch-in-vis-js) all but one.

```
network.on('click',function(eventParams){

    var edges = eventParams.edges;
    if(edges.length == 0)
        return;

    var edge = edges[0],
        fromID = edge.from,
        toID = edge.to;

    // get the nodes by ids, find all edges connecting them, hide all but the selected one
});
```

To advance it further to toggling, you have to check if any of the connecting edges are hidden show all if at least one is hidden, or hide all but one otherwise.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it ;)
I thought about this, but I was wondering if there was anything for that already implemented in vis.js.

Thanks!